# Suggested in memory database

Tags: in-memory-database

For increasing performance we want to duplicate part of our postgresql data to in-memory sql storage. At this moment I am searching for suggested in-memory relational database, it may run on either windows or linux. I will really appreciate any suggestions based on experience of usage or good references.

Comment: Have you considered sqlite? In case you didn't know this was possible for sqlite: https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html

Comment: @FrancescoGramano I know that this option exists, we want to compare several databases and to study all pros and cons. And maybe to hear from people that used them what the advantages. Thanks in any case.

Comment: The folks at www.trinity.co.il can give you some local references of users of in-memory database technology.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an In-Memory RDBMS for extreme SQL OLTP and analytics performance then try Oracle [TimesTen In-Memory Database](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/timesten/overview/index.html).

TimesTen runs on both Linux and Windows [and Solaris, AIX and HP-UX].
TimesTen runs as either a system or record [RDBMS] or as a read/write cache for the Oracle RDBMS.

Oracle will also soon release the shared nothing scalout version of TimesTen called [TimesTen Scaleout](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-fast-oracle-timesten-velocity-scale-douglas-hood/)